# Order of operations in custom expressions

Tags: user-expectation, math

In our system users can define behaviour based on condition expressions:

```
{{shippingCosts}} + {{numBooks}} * {{bookPrice}}
```

To most people this means (a + b) * c but to others this means a + (b * c).

Most of our users are non tech-savvy people. Should we honor the order of operations and explain this to our users or just calculate from left to right and risk confusing users that remember their math classes.

addition:
For the record I know the second option is clearly correct, the problem is the vast majority of our users do not.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an area with no defined standards, where either behavior would be acceptable and you just decide based on what the majority wants.  Instead, there is a clear *correct* behavior.  This is very well established in mathematics and software.*  It is taught to everyone in school (even if they don't remember it).

In my opinion, if you use the proposed method to allow mathematical conditions, you *must* do it correctly.  Honor order of operations (and also allow parentheses so that people have full control).  Why?

- It would just be "wrong" not to do so (sorry, I'm a programmer and quite biased about this).
- Not honoring precedence will confuse and then greatly annoy the people who do know what they are doing.
- If you don't follow the established mathematical rules, there will be no clear standard for your application's behavior, making it ambiguous and confusing.
- Users who don't "get it" may well be confused by this interface no matter how you implement it.

Ultimately, if this confuses your users, you should rethink the interface in a more fundamental way.  Perhaps you could make just a minor change to help people understand the behavior (such as displaying parentheses or other visual cues automatically to show the order of operation).  Or perhaps you need to do things in a totally different way.

*Well, there is postfix notation.  But in this context it is an esoteric curiosity that is not a good basis for a decision about behavior for non-technical users.

Comment: I am also a programmer and know what the clearly defined correct behaviour is. Hovever if you ask random people in the streets 90% wil not. So our choice is teaching 90% of our users something they wil consider needlessly complex behaviour and probably get wrong often. Or get reactions like yours from people that do know. This is basically a no-win scenario. That's why I wanted some opinions.

Comment: @martijnve, I agree that if 90% of users don't understand something, it's not acceptable to assume that knowledge.  That's why I suggested more fundamental changes may be needed.

Answer (score 1):

Go with a + (b * c).

With any approach you take there will be a some non-minimum percentage of users with the opposite precedence conception or "in confusion land", so you **would have to specify it to them anyway**, thus the best option is to do it with the correct math way.

I don't know how is the "user rotation" of your app, but although nowadays the majority of the users would take left-to-right precedence as intuitive, I suppose that the users won't be always the same people, so I wouldn't consider the majority criteria as a strong one here where you have the chance to apply the "right way".